# How can use the `extrudedBuildingsVisible` properties in iOS with HereMap SDK

Tags: ios, swift, here-api, heremaps-ios-sdk

I'm implementing 3d Map(buildings view) with the here-SDK for iOS but I can't find a way to achieve this. I have seen the work of HERE Maps 3D buildings for android But It not work with iOS

I followed this [link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/3.16/dev_guide/topics/map-extruded-buildings.html)

Here is my sample code

```
func mapSetup() {
    
    // Setup map viewx
    self.mapView.positionIndicator.isAccuracyIndicatorVisible = true
    self.mapView.positionIndicator.type = .current
    self.mapView.positionIndicator.isVisible = true
    self.mapView.extrudedBuildingsVisible = true
    self.mapView.landmarksVisible = true
    self.mapView.alpha = 1
    self.mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 15)
    self.mapView.zoomLevel = 0
    
    self.navigationManager.delegate = self
    self.mapView.gestureDelegate = self
}
```

Question:

How can I implement 3d Map(buildings view) in iOS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without tilt specified the map must look flat.

This is what I'm getting with the following code

```
let geoCoordCenter = NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: 49.260327, longitude: -123.115025)
self.mapView.set(geoCenter: geoCoordCenter, animation: .none)

self.mapView.positionIndicator.isAccuracyIndicatorVisible = true
self.mapView.positionIndicator.type = .current
self.mapView.positionIndicator.isVisible = true
self.mapView.extrudedBuildingsVisible = true
self.mapView.landmarksVisible = true
self.mapView.alpha = 1
self.mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
self.mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 15)

self.mapView.zoomLevel = 19
self.mapView.tilt = self.mapView.maximumTilt(atZoomLevel: 19)
```

[image]

Rome:

[image: Rome]

Paris:

[image: Paris]

Comment: Hi @Anatoly Sukhanov, Thanks for the replay, It did not work with Rome and Paris area, But works with the London area

Comment: It probably means that extruded buildings are not available in those areas. https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.17/dev_guide/topics/map-extruded-buildings.html: "Extruded buildings are available for most metropolitan areas in North America and Europe". Most, but not all.

Comment: Well actually it worked for me with both Rome and Paris (see the attached screenshots)